# How to modify member of multidimensional array with the help of pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I need to modify some element of two-dimensional char array using pointer. I have tried this:

```
char arr[5][5];
char** ptr = arr;
ptr[2][3] = 'a';
```

This is not the correct way to do so. It gives me access violation. What should I do?

Comment: Did your compiler give any warnings about this code?

Comment: Why do you think that a `char**` type (a pointer to another pointer) is the same as `char[][]` (a contiguous block of memory)?

Comment: Any object referred to by a `**pointer` is ***NOT*** a multidimensional array no matter what you've been told or taught.  A `**pointer` refers to a ***one***-dimensional array of pointers, with each pointer in that ***one***-dimensional array pointing to another completely separate ***one***-dimensional array of values.  Because of that, you can not access a true two-dimensional array (one defined using brackets as `array[][]`) with a `**pointer` value.  They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on what you actually want to do.

Here are some candidates of ways:

Way 1: allocate an array with pointers to each row and use that.

```
char arr[5][5];
char* arr_rows[5];
char** ptr;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) arr_rows[i] = arr[i];
ptr = arr_rows;
ptr[2][3] = 'a';
```

Way 2: use a pointer to an array

```
char arr[5][5];
char (*ptr)[5] = arr;
ptr[2][3] = 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

A character pointer pointer is a variable which points to a character pointer whereas your character matrix *arr* is a contiguous array of elements. What you want is a pointer which points to the first row of *arr*:

```
char arr[5][5];
char (*ptr)[5] = arr;
ptr[2][3] = 'a';
```